# LISP: Run program in Ubuntu

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ubuntu-14.04, sbcl

I am newbie in lisp
I have installed Clisp in my ubuntu 14.04 machine and SBCL too.

My Program in TextEditor looks like this:

```
( hello world )
```

but i am getting the following error:

```
 user@user:~/Desktop/lisp$ ./test.lisp
    ./test.lisp: line 1: i: command not found
```

Comment: Based on your reported error, you have not included the full file. Please run `cat test.lisp` and paste the full output of that command into your question.

Comment: How did you come up with that test program? `(hello world)` says you want to execute a command `hello` with argument `world`. Lisp doesn't have a built-in `hello` command. You should find a tutorial and follow that.

Comment: If you are new to Common Lisp, you probably should have a look at [Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Edst/LispBook/) (which includes exercises) or [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) (which gets practical quite early).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CLISP under a unix (like Ubuntu) you can simply add a shebang to the top of your file `#!/path/to/clisp` and in Ubuntu that would be `#!/usr/bin/clisp` and it will execute the code as a script.

You need the file to contain proper Common Lisp file like:

```
#!/usr/bin/clisp
(princ "Hello, world!")
```

And make the file executable with `chmod 755 <filename>`. Unless you have placed it in one of the directories in `$PATH` you'll need to enter the path to it. From the directory of the file simply `./<filename>` would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `clisp test.lisp`

Comment: It is giving error : *** - EVAL: undefined function I

Comment: maybe you want `(print "hello world")`